# How to detect the end of a get sequence in a proxy object?

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

In order to avoid error when accessing deeply nested properties, I wrote a proxy-returning function:

```js
const safe_access = obj =>
  new Proxy(obj, {
    get: (o, k) =>
      o[k] == null
        ? safe_access({})
        : typeof o[k] === 'object'
          ? safe_access(o[k])
          : o[k] });
```

Here's an example:

```js
const a = safe_access({});
a.x.y.z; // no TypeError
```

However in its current form `safe_access` is unable to tell when it has reached the end of the path. Meaning that it cannot return `undefined` to signify that the property truly doesn't exist. This also means that you *cannot* have default values:

```js
const a = safe_access({});
a.x.y.z || 42; // not 42

const {x: {y: {z = 42}}} = a;
z; // not 42
```

How can my proxy object detect the end of a property lookup?

Comment: Using this syntax, I don't think there's any way to know.  Interesting question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1934264/) more or less applies here, for the same reasons.

You can't detect the end of an access chain because nothing makes it any different from the preceding accesses. At runtime, the following code is effectively identical to `let r = a.x.y.z`.

```
let r = a;
{
    r = r.x;
    r = r.y;
    r = r.z
}
```

---

If you actually want to use this sort of safe navigation in code you're writing, the best is to use the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?.`) and [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) (`??`) operators added to the Javascript standard in 2020. They provide a neater, less confusing way to do this sort of thing, and are supported by all modern browsers.

```
let r = a?.x?.y?.z ?? 42;
```

If you need to support legacy browsers, you can get these operators from these two Babel plugins: ([[1]](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining), [[2]](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator)).

---

However, if you really want to implement "safe" access yourself, there *are* a few tricks you can use to get around this.

One trick, that probably requires the least additional work is to reserve one name to indicate the end of the safe access chain. (I've done something similar in Python in the past.)

```
function safe_access(value) {
    let obj = (typeof(value) === 'object') ? value : {};

    return new Proxy(obj, {
        value: value,
        get: function(target, property) {
            if (property === "$")
                return this.value;
            else
                return safe_access(target[property]);
        }
    });
}

let a = {'x': {'y': 123}};
// a.x.y is a proxy object
a.x.y.$ === 123
a.x.y.z.$ === undefined
```

Another trick is detailed in [this blog post](https://gidi.io/javascript/2016/02/07/using-es6-s-proxy-for-safe-object-property-access/).

Comment: That technique in the last blog post you reference is actually pretty cool.

Comment: optional chaining works in browsers nowdays

Answer (score 0):

An interesting option is to work with Promises. [Comlink](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/comlink/blob/main/src/comlink.ts#L396) has an interesting usage of this.

Expanding on [jirassimok's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59003920/9282417), if everything is async, then the termination token becomes "then".

```js
function safe_access(value) {
    let obj = (typeof value === 'object') ? value : {};

    return new Proxy(obj, {
        value: value,
        get: function(target, property) {
            if (property === "then")
                return this.value;
            else
                return safe_access(target[property]);
        }
    });
}

async function main() {
  let a = safe_access({'x': {'y': 123}});
  // a.x.y is a proxy object
  (await a.x.y) === 123
  (await a.x.y.z) === undefined
}

main();
```

This wasn't immediately obvious to me, as I've been using async/await for a long time now.